# How to make tumblr tags visible?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I have this theme:
http://ambitionthemes.co.vu/tagged/theme15

And it doesn't show any tags when I'm scrolling through the page, only when I go into the post I want. 
What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you haven't checked [tumblr's theme docs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes), you should do that to get familiar with tumblr's specific variables and overall formula.

Now for adding tags, it's different for every theme, and this one apparently didn't include the code within the {block:IndexPage}{/block:IndexPage} block(s), but only within the {block:PermalinkPage}{/block:PermalinkPage} section(s). So you can copy the code they used there:

```
<br>
{block:HasTags} {block:Tags}<a href="/{TagURL}"> #{Tag}</a> {/block:Tags}{/block:hasTags}
```

and paste it where it's needed (or wanted) within the IndexPage block(s), most likely within each block for every unique post type (photo, video, text, quote, link, chat, audio, answer, photoset) (you can check tumblr's theme docs for each unique tag).

For example, go to your blog, click Customize, then Edit HTML, then at around line 733, where it has:

```
{block:IndexPage}
<a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" width="100%"/></a>{block:ifShowCaption}
{block:Caption}<div class="caption text">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:ifShowCaption}<div class="entrybottom">{block:RebloggedFrom}source : <a href="{ReblogRootURL}">{ReblogRootName}</a> - with {/block:RebloggedFrom}  

<a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCount} notes</a>  </div>
{/block:IndexPage}
```

you can add in the code we found earlier (or customize it to your liking), to result in this:

```
{block:IndexPage}
<a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" width="100%"/></a>{block:ifShowCaption}
{block:Caption}<div class="caption text">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:ifShowCaption}<div class="entrybottom">{block:RebloggedFrom}source : <a href="{ReblogRootURL}">{ReblogRootName}</a> - with {/block:RebloggedFrom}  

<a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCount} notes</a>  
<br>{block:HasTags} {block:Tags}<a href="/{TagURL}"> #{Tag}</a> {/block:Tags}{/block:hasTags}
</div>
{/block:IndexPage}
```

(the 2nd to last line is new, inserted right before the closing div tag). You'll want to add that new line to every post type. For this theme you can press Ctrl+F and search for entrybottom (since that's the div class it assigns to the box containing the info below any post) and make sure each one has a tag section.